# wxPython install in Python27

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been trying to install wxPython in Python27.

I typed below command in Python27 dir, and installed it.

```
pip install wxPython
```

[image]

I expected the wxPython would be installed in Python27.

But, the wxPython doesn't work in Python27.

When I tried to import the wx, I got below error.

[image]

On the other hand, it works for Python3.

How could I get proper wxPython version for Python27?

The installed wx version is this.

[image]

This is the result of the command `python -m pip install wxPython`.

[image]

Comment: `the wxPython doesn't work`  is there any error raised?

Comment: I added the error on python27.

Comment: What is the output of the pip command? Are you sure it is the pip from the Python 2.7 installation? One way to be sure is to run it like this: `c:\[Python 2.7 Folder]\python -m pip install wxPython`

Comment: I added the result of your comment. One curious thing is pip version is 18.1, while 19.2.1 corresponding to `pip install wxPython` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I understand whats happening now: Your Python 3.7 almost always "wins" against 2.7 (due to the way its installed; we will not know because we cannot see how you activate one over the other according to your screenshots). At any rate, when you do

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

you will run Python 2.7. However, when you do

```
C:\Python27\pip
```

this will call the pip in the 3.7 (!), because it has precedence on `%PATH%` before the 2.7 one. If you would do `C:\Python27\scripts\pip.exe` you would call pip/install into 2.7! This is by the way what @RobinDunn suggested! If we look at your newest screenshot, we can see already that both 2.7 and 3.7 have wxPython installed.

So, accordingly, if you try:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import wx;print(wx.version())"
```

you should indeed be able to prove to yourself that the 2.7 has its wx properly running!